# how to find a word(string) in excel whether it is present in excel file (xlsx) or not?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how to find a word(string) in excel whether it is present in excel file (xlsx) or not ?

I have to find a string and replacing it with some other srting.

```
def xlsxElementsRemove():
    print(xlsxFileList)
    for i in xlsxFileList:
        data = pd.read_excel(i)
        data1 = data.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
        data1.columns = data1.columns.str.replace('Unnamed.*', '')
        for j in userInputForRemove:
            pattern = re.compile(j, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
            data1 = data1.replace(pattern, '', regex=True)
        data1.to_excel(i, index=False)

xlsxElementsRemove()
```

here i am getting one issue like suppose i have word "stackOverflow" in excel file(xlsx) but when i am giving input as "stac" , "stackOver" , "stackOverflo" its replacing. All i need when i give input as "stackOverflow" then only it should replace the word otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

```
def xlsxElementsRemove():
    global allElementInExcel
    allElementInExcel = []
    for i in local_xlsxFileList:
        wb = open_workbook(i)
        for s in wb.sheets():
            for row in range(s.nrows):
                col_value = []
                for col in range(s.ncols):
                    value = (s.cell(row, col).value)
                    try:
                        value = str(int(value.split()))
                    except:
                        pass
                    col_value.append(value)
                    col_value = [x for x in col_value if x]
                allElementInExcel.extend(col_value)
                allElementInExcel = (re.split(r'(?:[^\w.]|_)+', ','.join(map(str.lower, map(str, allElementInExcel)))))
        data = pd.read_excel(i)
        data1 = data.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
        data1.columns = data1.columns.str.replace('Unnamed.*', '')
        for j in userInputForRemove:
            if j in allElementInExcel:
                pattern = re.compile(r'\b'+j+r'\b', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
                data1 = data1.replace(pattern, "", regex=True)
        data1.to_excel(i, index=False)
xlsxElementsRemove()
```

This code has worked for me.
I have just written this script which will remove all singla character present in file.